# How to suppress the output of wmic

Tags: batch-file, wmic

Does anyone know how to suppress the msg "No Instance(s) Available." from the following command? Your help is highly appreciated in advance!

```
wmic process where (name="java.exe") get commandline | findstr /i /c:"xxx" 1>nul 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices where to place the `2>nul`, either

```
2>nul wmic process where (name="java.exe") get commandline | findstr /i /c:"xxx"
```

or you can do

```
wmic process where (name="java.exe") get commandline 2>nul | findstr /i /c:"xxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pipe stderr into stdout making it visible for your findstr command (thus ignoring "No Instance(s) Available." due to your filter):

```
wmic process where (name="java.exe") get commandline 2>&1 | findstr /i /c:"xxx"
```